# How to delete .csv file using phoneGap

Tags: file, cordova, csv, jquery-mobile, delete-file

We can create .csv file and write & Read Data form .csv file

We flowed this [File API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry)

Now We need delete .csv file.Please guide to us.We have person.csv file in Mobile Memory. We need deleted person.csv file

We tried like this

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.plugins.orientationLock.lock("portrait");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}
function gotFS(fileSystem) {

     fileSystem.root.getFile("CCIL/Settlement/RouteSalesDispatchedHeader"+namebranchIt+""+lastFour+""+numberofCountVist+".csv", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);



 //   fileSystem.root.getFile("CCIL/Settlement/RouteSalesDispatchedHeader.csv", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    //alert("seeeeee32");
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}
```

We need deleted Before Write File into SdCard .Please guide to us

Comment: First off all, i don't understand where those two upvotes come from because you didn't provide any kind of code nor why it is not working for you. There is a removing function described inside the documentation you linked. It listens on `remove`. 
Provide more information!

Comment: use the remove method

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes we tried like this 
function success(entry) {
    console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
    alert('Error removing directory: ' + error.code);
}

// remove this directory
entry.remove(success, fail);
but We don't have luck Please guide to us

Comment: provide all the code you used on your question

Comment: @jcesarmobile Now we add what we tried Please look once and Guide to us